# Return Value for SCOM Install command through powershell

Tags: powershell, scom

```
Install-SCOMAgent 
-PrimaryManagementServer $MgmtServer 
-DNSHostName $AgentDiscovered
-ActionAccount $Credential
```

this is the install command to install agents from power shell script

1. `$mgmtServer` - is the primary management server.
2. `$AgentsDiscovered` - is array of computer names that are discovered and on whom agent is to be installed.
3. `$Credential` - contains the credential necessary for installation.

Agents are getting installed. I want the agents installed successfully to be logged into a file.

How to get the return values of Install-SCOMAgent Command to verify if agents are installed successfully or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this block code on your script

`$test_installation = Get-SCOMAgent -DNSHostName $AgentDiscovered
if ($test_installation -eq $null)
{write-host $AgentDiscovered " is not installed on SCOM "$MgmtServer }
else 
  {
   if ($test_installation  -eq "success")
   {write-host $AgentDiscovered " is healthy and installed on SCOM server "$MgmtServer }
   else
   {write-host $AgentDiscovered " is not healthy but installed on SCOM server "$MgmtServer}
  }`

Answer (score 0):

The parameter -PassThru will output objects to the pipeline, so this allows you to pipe them to other cmdlets, or to store them into a variable.

I guess this will output one object per computer in $AgentsDiscovered .